# Forge Custom Markups not render in canvas

Tags: autodesk-forge

In my Forge I have implemented normal markups (rectangle, cloud text etc..) and custom markups representing symbols. I can manage to export a screenshot. Unfortunately, I am not able to render the custom symbols markups.
In the first Image, a screenshot of the forge viewer with all the markups - in the second, the snapshot. Is that anything that I am not considering properly? The function `renderToCanvas()` works only with predefine markups types?

[Forge viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH1ZP.png)

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qkxi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is a limitation of the markup extension. As we mention in this blog post https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/implementing-custom-markups, custom markups cannot be persisted either, so not having them appear in the screenshot is most likely related to the same limitation.

With that said, you could try "hacking around" the limitation by rendering the markups (they are basically just an `<svg>` overlay) yourself instead of relying on the `renderToCanvas` method.